# Javascript in ASP.NET is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm back at coding som .NET stuff and I thought I'd play with Javascripts / jQuery.
I've added my `/js/myscript.js` file and it loads when the pages has loaded.

In my js file I only have one call `alert('TEST')`.

Why isn't the alert triggered?

I'm on ASP.NET 4.0  - but I don' think that has anything to do with it.
Is there a way to detect if there is any conflict with other scripts?

This goes in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js" ></script>
```

After page is loaded, I can use Firebug and exapnd the script and see it's content. So the script is loaded.

**Embarrassing update**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Alert if jQuery is loaded
    alert('Test1');
}

alert('Test 2');
```

As you can see in the above code, I'd forgotten to add the `);` and the end of the  `jQuery(document).ready()` function.

After a long day, even the simplest things can go unnoticed.

Comment: Can you show how you've added it?

Comment: can you post your javascript code please?

Comment: what is the javascript code in the file which calls the `alert`?

Comment: @jbabey - This is such a noob error. I'd forgotten to add the `);` on the `jQuery(document).ready()` function.

Comment: if you add a semi colon: `alert('TEST');` does it work then?

Comment: So maybe vote to delete this Q and forget that I ever asked it? :-)

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - Adding `);` made it all work :)

Comment: SO the statement of "one call" is invalid as you DO have a call to the document load event handler :)  Glad you got it figured out. `$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('test'); });`

Comment: @Steven: Can we resolve this question? Maybe you can accept one of the answers below.

Comment: @Steven: good job for solving your own issue and for letting everyone know!

Comment: @Steven: happens to the best of us. write your own answer and accept it so people stop looking here :P

Answer (score 1):

Always check for Javascript Errors on something like this.
All modern browser have built in HTML/Javascript inspectors which you can use to check for these errors.

Comment: I alwys do. But this time Firebug console was not enabled and therefore it never reported the error. That's why I thought it was a .NET / Visual Studio thing. Enableing it gives me the warning.

Answer (score 0):

What does your myscript.js look like?

```
function x(){
  alert('TEST');
}
```

or just (which will execute on load):

```
alert('TEST');
```